# Problem int - long in C. Code works fine with int but not long. Why?

Tags: c

When I work with int, my code produces the correct results. But when I work with long value like here in the code, the code doesn't stop and I need to Ctrl-C to stop it. The functions `is_div` and `is_prime` work fine with `long`. The problem is in `prime_divs`. I modified the `int i` (in the loop) into `long i` and still nothing.

```
#include <stdio.h>

long is_div(long number, long i)
{
    // Vérifie si i est un diviseur de number
    return number % i == 0;
}

long is_prime(long number)
{
    // Vérifie si number est un nombre premier
    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++)
        if (is_div(number, i)) return 0;
    return 1;
}

long* prime_divs(long number)
{
    // Calcule la liste des diviseurs premiers de number
    long index = 0;
    static long prime_dividers[100];

    for (long i = 2; i < number; i++){
        if (is_prime(i) && is_div(number, i)){
            prime_dividers[index++] = i;
        }
    }
    return prime_dividers;
}

int main(void)
{
    long *res = prime_divs(1021406);
    for (long i = 0; i < 5; i++) printf("%li", res[i]);
}
```

Comment: Please don't edit your code to include suggestions after someone posts an answer.

Comment: i.e. If I suggest to use a `long` instead of an `int` in your code, don't edit your question to change the `int` to a `long`.

Comment: Are you sure that 100 elements of `prime_dividers` are enough for range to 1021406? I guess `prime_dividers[index++]` will go above index 100.

Comment: Please don't add "SOLVED" to your questions when they are solved. Just accept an answer.

Comment: Actually your program will crash because of what i486 said, and the way you have programmed your "hunt for primes" with the initial value of 1021406

Comment: This code does not have the problem that OP thought it does. OP just didn't give the program enough time to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algorithm used is quite slow as the prime test can take up to `n` tests.  OP is simply not waiting long enough as well identified by [@S.S. Anne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10795151/s-s-anne).

```
// Slow and wrong answer number <= 1
long is_prime(long number) {
    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++)
        if (is_div(number, i)) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

A much faster way only iterates up to  `√n` tests.

```
long is_prime(long number) {
  // Handle cases 3 or less.
  if (n <= 3) {
    return n >= 2;
  }

  // for (int i = 2; i < number; i++)
  // Notice this only iterates up to sqrt(number)
  for (int i = 3; i <= number/i; i += 2) {
    if (number%i == 0) return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}
```

Avoid the following as it can overflow for `number` near `LONG_MAX`.

```
for (int i = 3; i*i <= number; i += 2) {  // Overflow possible - UB
```

Bonus: Good optimized compilers see nearby `number/i` and `number%i` and perform only 1 `number, i` operation and get both the quotient and remainder.

Aside: Consider unsigned types for prime number evaluation.

Comment: Even `0xfffffffff` multiplied by itself overflows. For comparison, `0xffffffff` is `UINT_MAX` (just one `f` less).

Comment: @S.S.Anne True [0xfffffffff squared overflows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60746745/problem-int-long-in-c-code-works-fine-with-int-but-not-long-why/60748751?noredirect=1#comment107537988_60748751), yet `i` would not get so large in `for (int i = 3; i*i <= number; i += 2)` before trouble, With `number` near `UINT_MAX` like `FFFE 0001` and above  (and  `number` is a prime), `i` reaches 0xFFFF, `i*i` does not overflow, but next `i` as `0x10001` does overflow `i*i` and the loop does not stop.   Hence a use for the other loop `for (int i = 3; i <= number/i; i += 2)` which does not overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're using such a large number, your code takes a long time to work. If you wait, you'll see that it eventually does give a result.

Additionally, as mentioned in the comments, `100` elements of `prime_dividers` isn't enough. You'll need more, but I'm not sure how many. I would err on the side of caution and go with `10000`.

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried this and it did no work. I just tried it again to be sure, but no it is not working, even with a long i.

Comment: @Gwynbleidd Try it in `is_prime`, too.

Comment: I tried it, just forgot to edit it here in my code.

Comment: OK edit : the code work when I give an int. Here : long *res = prime_divs(1021). The code works with this number.

Comment: @Gwynbleidd Your code does work, but it takes a long time to run.